# bitcoin-cli getbalance does not match balance with bitcoin-cli listtransactions

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, listtransactions

version of bitcoin-cli 0.17.1

when I try

> bitcoin-cli getbalance

I get balance 0.00010471 BTC

when I try

> bitcoin-cli listtransactions "*" 1000000 >aaa.txt

and then calculate

> SUM(receive) - SUM(send) - SUM(fee)

I get 1.18202354 BTC

WHY???

Comment: Do you have any unconfirmed transactions or have you imported anything as watchonly?

Comment: No, I have not unconfirmed transactions and have not imported anything